# Output Caching with IIS7 - How To for an dynamic aspx page?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, cache

I have a RetrieveBlob.aspx that gets some query string variables and returns an asset. Eeach url corresponds to a unique asset.

In the RetrieveBlob.aspx a Cache Profile is set. In Web.Config the profile looks like (under system.web tag:

```
<caching>
  <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" />
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add duration="14800" enabled="true" varyByParam="*" 
           name="AssetCacheProfile" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Ok, this works fine. When I put a breakpoint in the code behind of RetrieveBlob.aspx, it gets triggered the first time, and all the other times not.

Now, I throw away the Cache Profile and instead I'm having this in my Web.Config under System.WebServer:

```
<caching>
  <profiles>
    <add extension=".swf" policy="CacheForTimePeriod"
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".flv" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".gif" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".png" policy="CacheForTimePeriod"    
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".mp3" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
    <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
         kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:08:00" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

Now the caching doesn't work anymore. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to configure under Caching tag of System.WebServer a Caching Profile for a Dynamic aspx page?

I already tried adding something like this:

```
<add extension="RetrieveBlob.aspx" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" 
     kernelCachePolicy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="00:00:30" 
     varyByQueryString="assetId, assetFileId" />
```

But it doesn't work.

An example of an url is:

http://{server}/{application}/trunk/RetrieveBlob.aspx?assetId=31809&assetFileId=11829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<caching>` tag that you have enabled in web.config under `system.web` is .net specific and IIS 7 will not address that caching content.
Now, the `<caching>` you has been configured in `system.webServer` is handled by IIS 7 module and should work.

If you are looking to enable caching for a specific page like RetrieveBlob.aspx, you will need to add it under `<location>` tag e.g.:

```
<location path="RetrieveBlob.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".aspx" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" varyByQueryString="assetId, assetFileId" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The easiest way to get this done using the IIS 7 UI. Here is my blog which talks about [File level authentication in IIS 7](http://dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Did-you-know-Enable-File-Level-Authentication-in-IIS-7-75.aspx), but you can do the same for Output Caching.

Go the **Web Site** (Default Web Site in our case)
Click **Content View**
Right click on the file e.g. *RetrieveBlob.aspx* -> **Switch to Features View**
Double click **Output Caching**
Now, click **Add...** and make the necessary caching changes

Comment: how do you cache for mvc application that doesn't have extension